# Append a string to each item of a comboBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I basically populate a comboBox with a range of numbers using the following code:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Cast<object>().ToArray())
```

The thing is that I'd like to have the unit of measurement comparing soon after the numbers. Thus my question, how can I add a string to each item of my comboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a Linq expression:

```
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(x => x.ToString() + " sufix").Cast<object>().ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the solution provided by Diego Rafauel Souza you could also append the text to each item of the combobox:

```
for (var index = 0; index < comboBox1.Items.Count; index++)
{
    var item = comboBox1.Items [index];
    comboBox1.Items[index] = $"{item} {suffix}";
}
```

This simply adds the suffix to every item of the comboBox.